# Not able to connect to beeline using connection string

Tags: hive, beeline

I am trying to set the alias for my beeline. And facing an issue.

if I login to `beeline` and then provide following connection string it works. It asks me for username and password and I am able to login.

```
!connect jdbc:hive2://<my_domain>:8449/;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/emr-cluster-top/hive;sslTrustStore=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts;trustStorePassword=changeit
```

However if I run following command, it's not working. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://<my_domain>:8449/;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/emr-cluster-top/hive;sslTrustStore=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts;trustStorePassword=changeit -n my_user -=p my_pass
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not establish connection to jdbc:hive2://<my_domain>:8449/;ssl=true;transportMode=http;httpPath=gateway/emr-cluster-top/hive;sslTrustStore=/etc/pki/ca-trust/extracted/java/cacerts;trustStorePassword=changeit: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.openSession(HiveConnection.java:699)
        at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:200)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: HTTP Response code: 401
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flushUsingHttpClient(THttpClient.java:262)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.THttpClient.flush(THttpClient.java:313)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:73)
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.sendBase(TServiceClient.java:62)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.send_OpenSession(TCLIService.java:162)
        at org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Client.OpenSession(TCLIService.java:154)
```

Comment: Here is the list of beeline options: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-BeelineCommandOptions. Note `-u` means URL, `-n` -- username.

Comment: @mazaneicha it was a typo. fix the command and updated with error message

Comment: Can you try to include the whole URL string in ""s and add `--verbose=true` to see detailed trace?

Comment: @mazaneicha updated the error message.

Comment: HTTP 401 means "Unauthorized". What authorization does your Hive2 use? Also, can you review HS2 log to see if it logged any errors regarding your connection.

Comment: Have you checked whether your kerberos ticket is available or expired? may be that is the issue.